# Equivalence class finding?

Tags: equivalence-relations

$c_1=a+ib$, $ $  $c_2 = x+iy$
$c_1 R c_2 <=> rec_1 = rec_2  $
$  $
Find all equivalence classes. I have no idea how to write them properly.

Comment: Two complex number are in same class if they have the same real part. So an equivalence class of $z=x+iy$ is given by $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\Re(z)=x\}$ (this is a vertical line in complex plane) so quotient space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a relation on $X$ characterized by $xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$ where $f$ is a function with domain $X$, then $R$ is an equivalence relation.

The equivalence class represented by $x\in X$ takes the form:

$$\{y\in X\mid f(x)=f(y)\}$$

Apply that on $X=\mathbb C$ and the function prescribed by $z\mapsto\text{Re}z$.